# Ajax call for JSON data works with FF, but not with other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, firefox

I have done a php page which returns a (valid) JSON document.
The jQuery code is very simple:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:8888/rkm/json-jc",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     $('li.jcarousel-item-1', context).html(
       '<img src="' + data.nodes['0'].node.vignette + '">'
     );
   }
});
```

It works fine in FF and the object returned is OK => see 'FF_console' attached.
But... it doesn't work in Chrome, Safari and Opera, without throwing errors. The data 'vignette' returned is just undefined => see 'Chrome_console' attached.
Thanks in advance for your help !

NB: jQuery version is 1.3.6
[image: Chrome iimage]
[image: FF image]

Comment: "see 'Chrome_console' attached"..

Comment: Are you sending json header from your php script?

Comment: look in the net tab of console to see what is actually sent. It sounds like you hav an invalid JSON problem. Can valdate at jsonlint.com

Comment: maybe stupid question, but where do I find the attachments?

Comment: @dfsq  images added, there was an issue.

Comment: In FireBug `nodes[0].node` is instance of `Object`, but in Chrome console it is instance of `Array`. Why? Check _Network_ tabs in both consoles for server output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 '<img src="' + data.nodes['0'].node.vignette + '">'
```

Should probably be

```
 '<img src="' + data.nodes[0].node.vignette + '">'
```

In addition to

```
 console.log(data);
```

It would be helpful to see

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest u to use latest jquery version 1.7+

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js